# ASP.NET MVC Routing issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging

Is there any tools or utilities to help in debugging ASP.NET MVC Routing issues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Phil Haack, one of the creators of ASP.Net MVC, put together a route debugger. You can [get it (with full source code) here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx).

Comment: You were quick! Guess I'll type it all up offthestack first.

Answer (score 2):

Glimpse also has a [plugin for route debugging](http://getglimpse.com/Help/Plugin/Routes).

[image: Glimpse route debugger]